# Java, lottery calculuator

Tags: java, combinations, permutation

Ok so i am really bored and have decided to make a lottery calculator type thing (yes i know, i am sad!)

Anyway, i was wondering if there was a java library method/class for working out permutations/combinations. I want to generate all possible number sets, that have 6 numbers from 1 - 49 with no repeats in them

If this isnt available as a pre written method, whats the best approach for me to write my own?

Thank you

Comment: You wouldn't happen to live in Germany, would you? ;)

Comment: german lottery has 1 - 49 numbers i think.. but there are also other countries...

Comment: Canada has Lotto649 too.  Same one in a gazillion odds of winning ;-)

Comment: Just to clarify... Do you want an actual set of all possible combinations? Or do you just want to know the actual max number of permutations so that you can calculate odds and such?

Comment: i want a list of 6number sets that form all possible combinations

Comment: Because everyone seems to get these confused: _permutations_ mean order matters, _combinations_ mean they don't.  Lottery numbers are always *combinations*, not permutations.

Answer (score 3):

A rough estimation:

```
49 * 48 * 47 * 46 * 45 * 44 = 10.068.347.520
```

This is the length of a *list* containing all possible combinations. Note that you can't use an `ArrayList` because this is backed by an array and an arrays maximum size is limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Even if you use `byte` arrays to store the ten billion combinations, you should start the jvm like this:

```
java -Xmx250G my.little.LotteryGenerator
```

(assuming you have sufficient memory on board)

Answer (score 2):

This is my second answer. Here's a stupid but easy approach to coding this problem (in Java):

```
for (int i1=1; i1<45; i1++) {
   for (int i2=i1+1; i2<46; i2++) {
      for (int i3=i2+1; i3<47; i3++) {
         for (int i4=i3+1; i4<48; i4++) {
            for (int i5=i4+1; i5<49; i5++) {
               for (int i6=i5+1; i6<50; i6++) {
                  System.out.format("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6);
}}}}}}
```

Comment: Nice try (I'd really like to see someone run this, heehee!), but you're little applet spits out permutations.  Lottery numbers are combinations, ie order doesn't matter.  Thus your solution prints 120 (5!) duplicates.

Comment: @Scott Biggs, I think you need to read my code a little more carefully.

Comment: Just to be sure, I wrapped a little Java program around it and ran it. It needed about a minute and the output file has 13983816 lines, which is exactly the number you'd expect from comb(49,6) (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=comb%2849%2C6%29) .

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the spaghetti code and horrible naming of variables (I stayed up till 3AM one night) writing my own lottery program in Java, but here ya go

```
 public static void LottoNumbers()
        {

          int zero=0;
 int one=0;
 int two=0;
 int three=0;
 int four=0;
 int five=0;
 int six=0;
 int bonus = 0;
 int bonusball=0;
            ArrayList myNumbers = new ArrayList();
            Random random2 = new Random();

            ArrayList ResultsList = new ArrayList<results>();
            ArrayList numberList = new ArrayList();

            for (int outer = 0; outer < 140000001; outer++)
            {
                myNumbers.clear();
                for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    boolean a = true;
                    while(a)
                    {
                    int r = random2.nextInt();
                    if (!myNumbers.contains(r)) {
                        myNumbers.add(random2.nextInt(49) +1);
                        a = false;
                    }
                    }
                }
                numberList.clear();
                for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    boolean a = true;
                    while (a)
                    {


                        Random random = new Random();
                        int r = random.nextInt(49) +1;
                        if (!numberList.contains(r))
                        {
                            numberList.add(r);
                            a = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Random random = new Random();
                boolean b = true;
                while(b)
                {
                int bb = random.nextInt(49) +1;
                if (!numberList.contains(bb))
                {
                    bonusball = bb;
                    b = false;
                }
                }

                int matches = 0;
                for (int u =0; u<numberList.size(); u++)
                {
                    if (myNumbers.contains(numberList.get(u)))
                    {
                        matches++;
                    }
                }
                if (matches == 0)
                        zero++;
                    if (matches == 1)
                        one++;
                    if (matches == 2)
                        two++;
                    if (matches == 3)
                        three++;
                    if (matches == 4)
                        four++;
                    if (matches == 5)
                        five++;
                    if (matches== 5 && myNumbers.contains(bonusball))
                        bonus++;
                    if (matches == 6) {
                        six++;

                             System.out.println("Jackpot! " + numberList.get(0)
                                     +"," + numberList.get(1)
                                     +"," + numberList.get(2)
                                     +"," + numberList.get(3)
                                     +"," + numberList.get(4)
                                     +"," + numberList.get(5));
                    }


if (outer%500000==0) {
                        System.out.println("none: " + zero + " one: " + one + " two: " + two + " three: " + three + " four: " + four +
                        " five: " + five + " 5+bonus: " + bonus + " six: " + six + " total: " + outer);
}
```

My initial theory was to run 6 random numbers against a set of 6 numbers chosen by myself. But I found the random number generator to be a little unreliable, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 would win around once a million, sometimes more! But I then decided to also generate my numbers randomly and the results I found were pretty accurate, at least in that a winning (UK based) set of 6 matching numbers appeared roughly once every 14 million iterations.

I was intrigued by the idea that every combination should appear once in 14million, and wanted to do 140million draws and see which numbers came up most. I gave up when I realised what a headache it would be storing all that data. So I just stuck in some print lines to output totals (ie. 5 matches) and any jackpots that occurred. Might help me pick a few numbers this weekend!

Before anyone fires any shots, I'm a new and enthusiastic programmer and know that this is a bit of a mess, but its just for fun :)

Edit: the program just finished its 140millionth loop, and there were 10 jackpots!

Comment: Now if only you could tie it into a real lottery, you would be a very rich man ;)

Answer (score 0):

Google on "permutations java" found [this](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/23recursion/Permutations.java.html).

Have fun!

Comment: hmmmm the have fun seems like it could havea double meaning ;)

Comment: No offense was intended; you indicated you were doing this because you were bored, i.e. "for fun." Personally, I feel that having the complete list of permutations is exactly as valuable as not having it, but to each his own!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for fun, should you not be doing it from scratch?

With extra points for imaginative code?  Looks like an ideal chance to try out recursion.

Think

getPermitations(length)
{
result = new Vector
tmp = getPermitations(lenght-1)

for (i = 0=>9)
{
for (String s: tmp)
{
  result.add(i + tmp);
}
}

}

Yes, I know that is not working code, where is the fun in copying someone else working code?

Then play with optimising it for extra points.

Comment: Or you could write something to actually build the full probability tree, creating a new object for every possibility.  I wonder if you run out of memory first!

Comment: Again, lotteries are COMBINATIONS, not permutations; order doesn't matter.  This pseudo-code will result in length! duplicates.